# Classification of JavaScript Libraries/Frameworks

Tags: javascript

I am starting learning JavaScript for web applications. Before this I have had experience with basic JavaScript and jquery for manipulating DOM elements. I have also worked on some AJAX.
Through Reading on the web recently I have found out that:

- JavaScript can be used on **server side** like in Node JS.
- The traditional JavaScript for **manipulating DOM** elements and **AJAX**
- It can be also used to build powerful applications (**client side**) based on the **MV***
  architecture [Like Backbone JS, Angular JS, Ember JS] using
  frameworks/libraries.
- Then there are  JavaScript frameworks/libraries for **micro-templates**
  [like underscore JS, HAML-JS], for AMD [require JS], Logic Less
  [Handlebars JS, Mustache, Dust JS].
- And also there is **coffeescript** that compiles to JS.

After all this reading I am awfully confused how JavaScript frameworks/libraries can be classified according to their

- **Side** [client side, server side, client-server side, browser side]
- **Function** [MV*, DOM scripting, micro templating etc.]

Can someone explain this mess with some examples of each library/framework. Also are there any **resources/books/slide** where I can get information on how JavaScript is used in different ways on the web.

Comment: I don't bother with any of this. I just use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: The last JS library I wrote works both in browsers and in node. It isn't really useful to try to put libraries into neat little boxes — they won't fit. Look for things that solve the problems you have not for things which solve specific hypothetical problems.

Comment: Found some great resource at
http://addyosmani.com/blog/tools-for-jquery-application-architecture-the-printable-chart/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is just a language , you are confusing the language and the API it has access to. 
On in the browser ,the API is the DOM period.

On the server the API is whatever software that uses Javascript as a scripting language.

NodeJS has an API that has nothing to do with the DOM , and furthermore , NodeJS javascript is not always compatible with the javascript that runs on the browser.

MongoDB ( a database using Javascript as a scripting language )  supports neither the DOM api nor nodeJS API but it's own API.

Fireworks (Adobe) uses javascript as a scripting language too , and the API has nothing to do with other "available" APIs.

Dreamweaver (Adobe) uses javascript with an API that is not even compatible with other Adobe products.

If you want to know what the Javascript language is about read the ECMAScript ( official name ) specification. Javascript is a very minimal language.

So when you find a framework/library/whatever , just check on what context the library is meant to be used. If you want to sort libraries you have to know the context of their use first.

On the client , there can be pure javascript libraries ( like underscore for instance that deal only with javascript objects) or deal with the DOM ( jQuery , any framework that uses AJAX since AJAX is part of the DOM , so most of the MVC/MVP/MVVM frameworks ) or both.

Then there are languages that compile to javascript ( typescript , coffeescript , dart , haxe ... ) it means you program in a language , you compile the source and you get some javascript on the end.

Comment: Thanks ..Till now I am not that familiar with javascript and by seeing all these new web technologies I was kind of blown away.

Comment: Again , javascript is just a scripting layer on top of something else. NodeJS API is C++ code beneath ,so is the DOM on webkit for instance. so API calls are directly mapped to C++ functions most of the time , you can get a look at webkit source for instance, it is a very interesting to know how all these things work. Javascript is a really a thin layer , there is nothing fancy about it.

Comment: JavaScript is converted directly to machine code now when running new versions of Safari....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore